# Map multiple values from distinct datas sources to common IRIs using JSON-LD context

Tags: json-ld

I want to use the JSON-LD context to map values that represent the same types of entities from multiple data sources to common IRIs.

Here is an example.
Suppose I have two data sources:

- DS#1 holds information about patients.
- DS#2 holds information about providers.

In DS#1, the "patient_gender" field has the following permissible values and definitions:

- "F": the patient is of female gender
- "M": the patient is of male gender

In DS#2, the "provider_gender" field has the following permissible values and definitions:

- "1": the provider is of female gender
- "2": the provider is of male gender

Now suppose I define two IRIs to represent females and males:

- `http://example.com/female` (represents females)
- `http://example.com/male` (represents males)

In the JSON-LD context, how do you map values "F" and "1" to `http://example.com/female`; and "M" and "2" to `http://example.com/male`?

Comment: Assuming it is defined in your context, how would you use this IRI in your JSON-LD?

Comment: I'm not sure. I suppose you would have to define somehow that (for example) a gender field with value "F" represents a female gender.